# Is there any way to chain trait object methods?

Tags: rust

I'm playing with rasterization and ray tracing, and my algorithm works on objects that can be rotated, translated, scaled, and converted to a bunch of triangles. I implement this by creating the IntoTriangle trait:

```
pub trait IntoTriangle {
    fn triangulate(&self) -> Vec<Triangle>;
    fn rotate(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32);
    fn scale(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32);
    fn translate(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32);
}
```

And then in my program I transform the object before converting it into triangles:

```
let obj = MyObjectType::new(...);
obj.scale(7.0, 7.0, 7.0);
obj.rotate(0.0, 45.0, 0.0);
obj.translate(3.0, 0.0, -30.0);
let triangles = obj.triangulate();
```

This code has been working for a long time. But recently I was going through a piece of unrelated code from `gtk-rs` and noticed how they stack up such calls in a very nice way, which I really loved because the usage becomes so much clearer:

```
let triangles = MyObjectType::new(...)
    .scale(7.0, 7.0, 7.0)
    .rotate(0.0, 45.0, 0.0)
    .translate(3.0, 0.0, -30.0)
    .triangulate();
```

To achieve this I would need to change scale/rotate/translate functions to take `mut self` and return `Self` (this is inspired by the gtk-rs code: https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/src/gtk4/auto/application_window.rs.html#428-431 ):

```
fn rotate(mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> Self {
    self.rotation = [x, y, z];
    self
}
```

But this is not object-safe and the compiler won't let me do this unless I move these functions out of the trait.
Is there any other way of achieving similar behaviour for trait objects? I'm at the point where I'm almost ready to move these methods out of the trait for the sake of retaining this gtk-inspired look and feel.

Comment: The methods could themselves [return trait objects](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70b24a0223a50c8360f5128837a75e84), which would just be implemented by returning `self`.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap everything in a builder over generic `IntoTriangle` objects:

```rust
struct Triangle {}

trait IntoTriangle {
    fn triangulate(&self) -> Vec<Triangle>;
    fn rotate(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32);
    fn scale(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32);
    fn translate(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32);
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Fake {}

impl IntoTriangle for Fake {
    fn triangulate(&self) -> Vec<Triangle> {
        vec![]
    }
    fn rotate(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) {}
    fn scale(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) {}
    fn translate(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) {}
}

struct TriangleBuilder<T> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<T: IntoTriangle + Default> TriangleBuilder<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Default::default(),
        }
    }

    pub fn build(self) -> Vec<Triangle> {
        self.inner.triangulate()
    }

    pub fn rotate(mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> Self {
        self.inner.rotate(x, y, z);
        self
    }

    pub fn scale(mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> Self {
        self.inner.scale(x, y, z);
        self
    }

    pub fn translate(mut self, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> Self {
        self.inner.translate(x, y, z);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let triangles = TriangleBuilder::<Fake>::new()
        .rotate(0f32, 0f32, 0f32)
        .scale(1f32, 1f32, 1f32)
        .translate(3f32, 4f32, 5f32)
        .build();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0c0919fdf9362f3269b91dbc1b82d79)

Note that I use a `Default` bind for the implementation (for simplicity). But if needed you could have a constructor that takes the object itself or a reference if you needed.